# Let $z\bar z -(3-4i)z-(3+4i)\bar z + 21=0$. If M and m are max and min values of $\frac{z-\bar z}{i(z+\bar z)}$, then find $\frac 1M +\frac 1m$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z=x+iy$

Solving the above equation we get

$$x^2 +y^2-6x-8y+21=0$$
Which indicates a circle centered at $(6,8)$ of radius $2$

Also the require value of $|\frac yx|$

How do I find the max and min of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^2 +y^2-6x-8y+21=0$ represents a circle of center $(3,4)$ and radius $2$. Parametrize the circle with $x-3=2\cos t$ and $y-4=2\sin t$. Then
$$\frac{z-\bar z}{i(z+\bar z)}=\frac yx = \frac{4+2\sin t}{3+2\cos t}=f(t)\tag1$$

Set $f’(t) =0 $ to get $4\sin t+3\cos t+2=0$, leading to $\tan\frac t2 = 4\pm \sqrt{21}$. Substitute into $f(t)$ in (1) expressed in the form

$$f(t) = \frac{4(1+\tan\frac t2 +\tan^2\frac t2)}{5+ \tan^2\frac t2}
$$
and obtain
$$f_{max} =M= \frac25 (6+\sqrt{21}),\>\>\>\>\>
f_{min}=m = \frac25 (6-\sqrt{21})$$
Thus,

$$\frac1M+\frac1m= 2
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, I don’t know how you converted from (1) to $f(t) = \frac{4\left(1+\tan\frac t2 +\tan^2\frac t2 \right)}{5+ \tan^2\frac t2}$?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon - use half-angle substitutions

Comment: Thanks! Nice proof!

Comment: Is there a way to solve using conics ie. finding out slopes using triangles etc.?

Comment: @Aditya - there is. $M= \tan( \alpha + \beta)$ and $m= \tan( \alpha - \beta)$, where $\tan \alpha = \frac43$ and $\tan\beta = \frac2{\sqrt{21}}$

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line $y=kx$ reaches its minimum or maximum when it's tangent to the circle $x^2 +y^2-6x-8y+21=0$. This happens when $x^2+k^2x^2-6x-8kx+21=0$ has duplicate roots, i.e, the discriminant is zero:

$$(1+k^2)x^2-(8k+6)x+21=0 \implies (8k+6)^2 = 4(1+k^2)\cdot 21 \\\implies 5k^2-24k+12=0$$

Therefore $\frac 1m + \frac 1M=\frac{m+M}{mM} = \frac{24/5}{12/5}=2.\blacksquare$